# Canonical way to build a plug-in system in Python

Tags: python

I'll try to keep this question objective. What is the canonical way to build a plugin-system for a Python desktop application?

Is it possible to have an easy to use (for the developer) system which achieves the following:

- Users input their code using an in-app editor (the editor could end up dumping their plugins into a subdirectory of the app, if necessary)
- Keep the source of the application "closed" (Yes, there are pitfalls to obfuscation)

Thanks

Comment: i observe that a plugin system would make any sort of "closed" python source even leakier than usual, since a plugin could make use of whatever debugging features it wished and merely wait for you to call it

Comment: If you use PyPy you can run plug-ins in sandboxes, which should prevent some of the pitfalls that CPython has. However I'm not an expert in PyPy and I don't know whether this would make it impossible for the plug-in to make contact with the main application.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you need some sort of educational system where the user can submit code, presumable to check that the code performs cf. a exercise.

My immediate thoughts about this would to use a web-interface. In this manner, the code of the evaluating system is entirely hidden (unless the student hacks your webserver, but this is an entirely different topic).
However, for this to work you must be aware of the pitfalls of allowing others submit code to your service, that is then executed. The code must be rigorously checked for the obvious things, but the issues here are open-bounded. You must also protect your service from the back-end by providing a safe environment for executing (e.g. a sandbox).